# Почему не работает подключение SVG через тег img

Tags: html, css, svg

Экспортировал логотип в `svg` из `фотошопа`, вот его код:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="43" height="47" viewBox="0 0 43 47">
  <metadata><?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c138 79.159824, 2016/09/14-01:09:01        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""/>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>                          
<?xpacket end="w"?></metadata>
<image id="android-logo.svg" width="43" height="47" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/>
</svg>
```

Подключаю к `HTML` с помощью `<img>`

```html
<img src="img/logo.svg" alt="bbbbb">
```

Путь правильный, имя файла тоже, но не отображается на странице

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всё вы сделали правильно, за исключением того, что рисовали svg в растровом редакторе.
 Получается, что вы растровую картинку обернули в формат `base64`. 
А это на самом деле не чисто векторный формат, поэтому масштабироваться будет, как картинка `png`.
 Кроме того такой формат не стилизуется. И если вы захотите поменять цвет иконки, то через стили это не получится, только применяя фильтры SVG.

**Вывод один,- векторные изображения нужно рисовать в векторных редакторах.**

Я загрузил ваш файл `logo.svg` на сервер и пробовал добавить его в `HTML`

```html
<img src="https://svg-art.ru/files/logo.svg" width="43" height="47" >
```

Работает в `Firefox`, `Chrome`, `Opera`, `IE11`, `Edge`, но стилизация, интерактивность  будет не доступна.

Подключайте с помощью тега `<object>` работает во всех браузерах:

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://svg-art.ru/files/logo.svg" width="43" height="47" >
   Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Google Material Icons

В отличии от метода экспортирования изображения из фотошопа данный метод позволяет легко стилизовать, трансформировать иконки без потери качества и работает во всех браузерах.

Во многих случаях можно использовать [символьный шрифт svg иконок от `Google`](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#using-the-icons-in-html), состоящий из 900 иконок.  И ваша иконка андроида тоже есть в этом наборе.

Подключение и использование шрифта от `Google` не составит труда

- Подключение шрифта:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">`

- Выбирать иконки по названиям можно [здесь](https://material.io/icons/)
- Пример использования гугловского символьного шрифта:

```css
i {
  margin: 100px 50px 50px 80px;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
i:hover {
  transform: scale(10);
}

.red{color:red}
.green{color:yellowgreen}
.blue{color: dodgerblue}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="material-icons red">android</i> 
<i class="material-icons green">android</i>
<i class="material-icons blue">stars</i>
```

Comment: это мое первое посещение сайта, не знаю еще, как тут принято. Спасибо за ответы!